# Why is there a tiny margin appearing to the right of my DIV?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a large DIV of 586px width. Within this are two smaller DIVs, both 266px width.

When I preview the page though, there's a small margin in between them. I've tried troubleshooting this with Inspect Element, but not found any extra margins in the metrics.

[image: screengrab from Safari]

The CSS:

`#category-results      {
                        width: 586px;
                        height: 1000px;
                        background-color: fuchsia;
                        }`

`.category-item-full        {
                        height: 158px;
                        width: 266px;
                        background-color: green;
                        position: relative;
                        display: inline-block;
                        margin: 0px;
                        }`

The HTML:

`<div id="category-results">`

```
                    <div class="category-item-full">
                    </div>

                    <div class="category-item-full">
                    </div>
```

`</div>`

Comment: Are these inline blocks? Do you have whitespace or newlines between your div tags in your HTML source? If so, there's the issue.

Comment: Please post the full html and css

Comment: Just added the CSS and HTML, thank you.

Comment: BoltClock, I put the DIVs on one line like so `<div class="category-item-full"></div><div class="category-item-full"></div>` but I don't understand why this white-space is included if they're on separate lines.

Comment: You can thank HTML parsing for that. All extraneous white space (including line breaks) is condensed to a single space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `display: inline-block;` in your CSS.
Or, if you need it, remove white space between `<div>`s in HTML:

```
<div class="category-item-full">
</div><div class="category-item-full">
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. `Inline-block` is making the white space get parsed, right?

So this gives me a new problem. If I remove `inline-block` then my smaller DIVs take up the entire row, instead of sitting next to each other.

How do I get around that without `inline-block`?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly as you said. To get around it, try googling for *css floating*.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have empty white space between your divs. Tighten them up and it goes away. **[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pUc8/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS resets. Here's one to get you started: [CSS Tools: Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). And, feel free to google away "CSS reset." Finally, the [tuts+ network](http://tutsplus.com/) is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of `display: inline-block` and replacing with `float: left`.  Seems to work, and is standard CSS unlike "inline-block".